# Database for issue tracker suggestion

Tags: database

here is a database i built for a project issue tracker , how ever i got a question i want to assign a user to solve an issue sould i create a another table named for example AssignedTo then i add to it the userID as a foreign key from the userTable , then add the AssignedTOID into the issuetable as a foreign key ? or there is way to implement it
what i did so far is that user can create one or to many projects and a project can have one or too many issues

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question depends entirely on the cardinality. The way you have described it then you only need a userID in the Issue table, as each Issue is assigned to a single user. This table would also include the other details - when assigned, when resolved, etc.

However you might find that you end up having a many-to-many between issue and user, if an issue may be assigned to multiple users, or perhaps escalated from one user to the next. In that case you need an additional AssignedTo table with FKs into both issue and user.

I suspect the same might be true between Project and User, unless every project is only ever worked on by a single user.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you , what would be the best approach to make a many to many relationship

Comment: Many to many between User and Issue is simply a table that either has a primary key made up of IssueID and UserID, both of which are also FK into the relevant tables, or with its own AssignID and normal FK into the other two tables. You can add any other suitable columns such as AssignDate. In a theoretical situation the primary key would be (IssueID,UserID), but in practice you might find it easier to use a separate AssignID.